# How do I get IntelliJ autocomplete to include implicit conversions/classes by default

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a series of implicit classes. How do I setup IntelliJ such that they appear in the autocomplete menu by default (without having the already imported)?

EDIT: for clarity stake, I am referring to the popup context menu that appears when you start writing code.

Comment: Hey, can you please state an example of code or any screenshot. that would be helpful in understanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that's possible. You will have to have imported the conversions or extension-methods first. What you *can* do however, is start typing the extension method and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> **twice** which brings up the possible places that provide such a conversion, and then you can use the cursor keys and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to let IntelliJ add the relevant import and then complete the method name.

For example,

`Seq("ls", "-la").!`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>

[image]

Comment: (it also works when you press those keys immediately after the period, but then you will have a hard time finding the right method because the list is very long).

Comment: I just gave this a go and its surprisingly slow. I'd expect it to be as quick as Resharper for Visual Studios....is there any way to make it quicker?